# Mock jndi connection

Tags: rest, junit, jersey, mockito

I have a little problem to mock my jndi connection at rest service. I'm use the jersey 1.9 to create the webservice rest and mockito for my tests.

My test code:

```
    //Mock DATA
    db = Mockito.mock(Transactions.class);

    Comp comp = Mockito.mock(Comp.class);

    Mockito.when(db.createConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
    Mockito.when(db.getComponent(connection, comp)).thenReturn(new Comp());
    Mockito.doNothing().when(connection).commit();
    Mockito.doNothing().when(connection).close();

    //Get class at the context
    configs = ConfigDatabaseTests.getInstance();
    configs.setUpClass();
    configs.bindNewSubContext("java:/comp/env/rest");
    configs.bindNewInstance(new WSCompRest(db), "java:/comp/env/rest/ws");
    webService = (WSCompRest) configs.getTheInstance("java:/comp/env/rest/ws");

    String jsonComp = "{\n"
            + "  \"comp\": {\n"
            + "    \"model\": \"XPTOXXX\",\n"
            + "    \"id\": \"TTTT\",\n"
            + "    \"type\": \"XXXXXX\"\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}";
    //END Mock DATA

    webService.createComp(jsonComp);
```

At this point i don't have anyproblem, the webService called and I can debug into the method.

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createComp(String comp) throws AppException {

    Response response = null;
    RequestHelper rqHelper = new RequestHelper();
    Comp com = new Comp();

    try {

        //Check parameters
        if (!rqHelper.validParameters(comp)) {
            throw new AppException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), "Invalid json!!");
        }

        ...

        Connection conn = db.createConnection();

        try {

            //Get the type
            //WHYYYYYYYYY?
            comp = db.getComponent(conn, comp);
            ...
```

I don't understand why the method getComponent(...) return a null instance... Anyone know a solution for this?
I had tested all the Transaction.class method using this strategy https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit but i like test the code at high level.

If i used spring it was easier then jersey to test the service? I question this because at spring it is possible inject the jndi using xml file.

Thanks all and sorry my bad English :(
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because when you set up your mock you specified that the method should only return a `new Comp()` if it was called with 2 specific objects (`connection` and `comp`):

```
Mockito.when(db.getComponent(connection, comp)).thenReturn(new Comp());
```

Your `comp` variable is a mock in the test code, but in your non-test code you call the method with a real `Comp` instance. I think what you actually want is for the method to return this value any time it is called, you should do something like this;

```
Mockito.when(db.getComponent(any(Connection.class), any(Comp.class)).thenReturn(new Comp());
```

Comment: thanks man...it works ;). You have any ideia who can call the real getComponent method? It is good i get an real value.